# How to calculate numbers with dot thousand separator in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, math, numbers, number-formatting

I've converted numbers using php number format as follows:

```
number_format($X, 2, ',', '.');
```

which converts

```
5000000
```

into

```
5.000.000,00
```

which is exactly what I wanted.

But now my javascript function which is doing some basic math on those numbers are giving wrong result, for example:

```
5.000.000,00 - 3.500.000,00 = 1.5 instead of 1.500.000,00
```

So how do you properly calculate those numbers in javascript?

I really appreciate any help i can get :D

Thanks y'all

Comment: Remove all the `.` and replace `,` with `.`. Then parse the string with `parseInt` to cast it to a number for calculation.

Comment: Or if you want want to use @Derek朕會功夫's response you could always pass 2 numbers to your JS. The first is the formated value, the second is the actual value.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 This is a horrible advice. It introduces a hard coded adoption which for obvious reasons can easily fail. The `number_format()` call typically is part of a localization layer, so does not format in a fixed manner.

Comment: I suggest you add the unformatted number as a data attribute to the formatted number string (you may have to put that into a container) and do your computations on those data values.

Comment: @arkascha That is not a horrible advice. I assume `5.000.000,00` is a string fetched from some data from somewhere. OP probably also tried to parse it but failed. (It would yield a syntax error if not parsed.) Unfortunately other than directly using the number format the specification specified, parsing is the only way to go.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 The OP clearly explains where that string comes from and why it was changed from a plain number which it was before to this string format. Your advice says it is good practice to code numbers later used for computations as strings inside the markup and hard code a blind reformatting. That simply is a horrible advice, sorry. Compare my constructive comment instead and take a look at the answer below which put my suggestion into code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatted numbers are for human eyes and not suitable for JS processing. You may want to either write the numbers as is in HTML and do the formatting on client side, or add a separate data attribute for the raw value.

For example:

```
<span id="myNumber" data-value="<?=$X?>"><?=number_format($X, 2, ',', '.')?></span>
```

Which gives you:

```
<span id="myNumber" data-value="5000000">5.000.000,00</span>
```

You can then get the raw number by JS:

```
var X = parseInt(document.getElementById("myNumber").getAttribute("data-value"), 10);
```

Or jQuery:

```
var X = parseInt($("#myNumber").attr("data-value"), 10);
```

Comment: hi @feliscatus , as your example, is this how you get the value using jquery?

    var X = parseFloat($('#myNumber').attr('data-value').val());

Comment: thank you all for the answers, need some work, but felis' gave the best solution so far. thanks again ;) (y)

Comment: @azheeq I have updated the answer to include a jQuery version as well. Please accept the answer by clicking on the green check if it works for you.

Comment: I've just found a much practical solution, using jquery addon from this project: 

   [github jquery number](https://github.com/customd/jquery-number)

But your solution is still the most helpful, so I'm gonna accept as the answer :D

Comment: If you decide to take the client-side-formatting approach, you can provide a different answer to your own question with code that uses `jquery-number`. Sharing your knowledge can really help others a lot should they run into the same problem.